# Apache POI: adding image(s) into worksheets containing charts

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache POI, I can add image(s) into worksheets without chart but it doesn't work worksheets with charts

The problem: impossible open the output file by excel!

Why not? Is there a solution?

```
InputStream inputStreamXls = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\template.xls");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStreamXls);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
inputStreamXls.close();

InputStream inputStreamImg = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\logo.png");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStreamImg);
int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
inputStreamImg.close();

CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(x);
anchor.setRow1(y);
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

// save workbook
String file = "c:\\temp\\output_file.xls";
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: I read this interested thread http://osdir.com/ml/user-poi.apache.org/2009-08/msg00104.html. I will try with JExcelAPI ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses XSSFWorkbook to read and write .xls files. XSSFWorkbook is for .xlsx files. Use HSSFWorkbook.